# Access to restricted URI denied : createHttpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am learning and trying to wire up AngularJS with Node and Express. But when I request the '/' path, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Access to restricted URI denied
createHttpBackend/<@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9902:6
sendReq@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9703:0
$http/serverRequest@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9415:15
processQueue@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:13292:26
scheduleProcessQueue/<@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:13308:26
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:14547:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:14363:14
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:14652:12
done@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9734:35
completeRequest@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9924:6
requestLoaded@file:///D:/Mean/routing/js/angular.js:9865:0
```

And in the console, I do not see any hits to the path as well. But when I run localhost:3000 in my browser, it hits.

This is my angular controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/'
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.name = data.name;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.name = 'Error!';
    })
})
```

And my server:

```
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http');

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var name = 'NameFromWeb';
    res.send(name);
})

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

I know that it is something related to running the index.html file directly and not from the server. But I don't have a clear idea of it.